# Is it possible to create a custom field or sub field for a Kubernetes object in c#

Tags: kubernetes, field

I want to add a sub field to a standard k8s object, such as a V1Deployment or V1Secret, is this possible, and if so how?

I looked for commands which might allow me to add a sub field, but couldn't find any. I also tried using a yaml file and patching existing objects by including the sub field I wanted in the object's body, but (as exacted) this gave an error due to the sub field not being recognized.

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotations to attach arbitrary metadata to objects, for example:

```
{
  "kind": "Deployment",
  "apiVersion": "extensions/v1beta1",
  "metadata": {
    "annotations": {
      "my-key": "my-value"
    }
  }

...
```

Official documentation for reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/working-with-objects/annotations/